# Find a spanning set of the smallest possible size for the subspace of $P_3$ consisting of polynomials with roots at $x=0, x= \pm1$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Find a spanning set of the smallest possible size for the subspace of $P_3$ (the polynomials of degree $3)$ consisting of polynomials with roots at $x=0, x= \pm1$. How many elements does it have?

Let $p \in P_3$. Now $p(x)=a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ if the roots of $p$ are $0, \pm1$ then $$p(x)=(x-0)(x-1)(x+1)=(x-0)(x^2-1)=x^3-x$$ but I'm not sure what is the set spanning this? In general for $P_3$ the one spanning set would be the set $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$, but I'm not sure I see what the spanning set would be for $x^3-x$ is this just the singleton $\{1\}$?

Comment: You have an error: $p(x)=a_3x(x-1)(x+1)=a_0(x^3-x)$. So the basis is $\{x^3-x\}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how is $(x-0) = a_3x$?

Comment: I didn't say that, but that all polynomials of degree $3$ which have $0,\pm 1$ as roots are scalar multiples of $x(x-1)(x+1)=x^3-x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bernard has already given the answer in his comment, but let me elaborate a little more on it: let $p\in P_3$ with roots $0$ and $\pm 1$. Then $p$ is of the form
$$p(x) = q(x)(x^3-x)$$
for some polynomial $q$. But $x^3 -x$ is already of degree 3, so $q$ must be constant. Therefore all the polynomials you are looking for are a scalar multiple of $x^3-x$, so $\{x^3-x\}$ is a basis, in particular a spanning set.